# In a loop with buttons: toggle a class on_click in only the button clicked

Tags: javascript, css, class, button, onclick

CSS:

```
.btn-category-list-col {
    background:#f4f6f9;
    border: 0 !important;
}
.btn-category-list-col:hover {
    background: #E2EEFC;
}
.btn-category-list-col button:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-category-list-col-click {
    background: #E2EEFC;
}

.btn-category-list-col-click button {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Looped button:

```
<td class="p-0 btn-category-list-col">
    <button type="button" value="${cat.category_id}" class="category_sort btn float-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createCategory">${cat.category_name}</button>
</td>
```

Script

```
        $(document).on('click', '.category_sort', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $(".btn-category-list-col").toggleClass("btn-category-list-col-click");
        });
```

[image: 1]

As you can see, my onclick function changes all the classes (.toggleClass) instead of the button clicked since all buttons are the same due to the loop, how do I make it specifically to only the button i clicked?

Comment: r u trying to the change the color on btn click?

Comment: is it inside a `<form` ? why do you use `e.preventDefault();` ? and also please add [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @saurabh changing the css on click

Comment: @MisterJojo sry I just took out the other code just to highlight toggleClass

Answer (score 1):

you can use the attribute selector of jquery to target the specific button instead of selecting the class.

assuming `cat.category_id` is unique

```
<!-- add data-id attribute to it-->
<td class="p-0 btn-category-list-col">
    <button type="button" value="${cat.category_id}" data-id="${cat.category_id}" class="category_sort btn float-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createCategory">${cat.category_name}</button>
</td>
```

```
 $(document).on('click', '.category_sort', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   let id = event.target.dataset.id;
   if (id) {
     $(`button[data-id=${id}]`).toggleClass("btn-category-list-col-click");
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding why you are asking for a javascript answer when you present jQuery code in your question.
So, here is your solution

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('.category_sort')
  .forEach(bt=>
  {
  bt.onclick = e =>
    {
    e.preventDefault()
    bt.closest('.btn-category-list-col').classList.toggle('btn-category-list-col-click')
    }  
  })
```